# How to create Access button on form to generate report of filtered data

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have created a form in Access and a report in Access.  The form is a searchable form, its format is continuous, it's used to search for medical providers that meet certain criteria in a number of textboxes.

The current dream is to, after you have searched for the providers that meet your criteria, click a button, and the report populates with only the filtered data points.

The table connect to the form has the fields:

GroupID: Number
OpenClosed: Yes/No
GroupName: Short text
ServiceType: Short text
Address: Short Text
PhoneNumber:  Short Text
City:  Short Text
Zip:  Number
State: Short Text
Tier: Number
Age: Short text
Insuarnce: Short text
Notes: Long text
EnteredOn:  Date

The report returns the following:

GroupName
Address
PhoneNumber
City
Zip
State

While researching on the internet I have just been finding info on how to open a report on the one record you are on.  I have tried to use those methods with no success.  I would love if I could click a button and open the report displaying only the filtered records.

I am pretty novice at Access, so detailed or step-by-step responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: I used that link to build the form, my searchable form works great.  The issue is now to have a printable report of the results, so once we filter and see all the providers we need, we can print up the results and give them to the patient.  Printing a form, as you know, does not look great.  I have heard that you should convert it to a report, which is much more printer friendly, and print that.  However I am having trouble producing a report that has only the filtered results from the form.

Comment: Use the code from link to build filter criteria string and use that string in OpenReport command WHERE argument. The article describes that.